# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot after installation "no UMS support in radeon module"

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I attempted a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS yesterday via LiveDVD. The installation went smoothly, but upon boot I am presented with a black screen with a single line of text at the top that states :

[drm:radeon_init [radeon]] * ERROR * no UMS support in radeon module!

Then, after a few seconds it does to a grayish screen where i can move my cursor around but nothing else appears.

I've done a fair amount of research on this error but can't seem to find much help. I'm aware of the AMD/ATi driver issues people have been having surrounding the removal of fglrx and such, but the issues result in poor gpu performance. I can't boot. I can however boot it if I try it without installing.

I've tried turning "nomodeset" on and off, same outcome.

I also don't believe it has anything to do with the Gnome environment because other forums seem to show people having this issue in multiple different environments.

Please help, I'm at a loss!
Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273471/how-to-solve-drmradeon-init-radeon-error-no-ums-support-in-radeon-module <- The comment there gives a suggestion that is worth trying. If you do and it doesn't work please edit you question and add that information.

Answer (score 1):

I would try pressing tab when you get to the menu, then add this: `radeon.dpm=0`
I was in a similar boat and had success using this.

Comment: I was getting absolutely no where and had to use `radeon.modeset=0` switch in grub. Your fix above took care of my issues. Thanks! (FWIW, I have an AMD A6-5400K APU)